# How can I check a text file for a certain phrase?

Tags: batch-file

So I have a zip file, and within the zip file I already found a way to display the contents of the zip file without unzipping it (which is important in my case) by outputting it into a text file. How can I then read from the text file to check if the contents of the zip file has a certain phrase, and report back to me whether it does or not? I don't need to know how many there are inside, just that there is one.

For example, I use this line to extract the contents of the zip file:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -r %%a > temp.txt
```

If the output is

```
7-Zip [64] 15.05 beta : Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Igor Pavlov : 2015-06-14
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 304 bytes (1 KiB)

Listing archive: Test.zip

--
Path = Test.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 304

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  -----------------------
2015-07-29 15:41:14 ....A            0            0  feel1.txt
2015-07-29 15:40:58 ....A            0            0  fall2.txt
2015-07-29 15:41:26 ....A            0            0  fell3.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  -----------------------
2015-07-29 15:41:26                  0            0  3 files
```

how can I get it to tell me whether it has "feel" inside the zip file?

Comment: You could use [findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490907.aspx)

Comment: We need code.  By what mechanism are you doing the unzip, and what statement directs the output to temp.txt?

Comment: I'll modify the original post, hold up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output can be redirected to **findstr** command to match the given string you are looking for :

```
set result=
type temp.txt| findstr /i "feel" && set result=true
if %result% == true echo file name exists in the zip entry.
```

here temp.txt contains the output of content of your zip file.
Please remove /i if you want your search to be case sensitive.

you can use **find** command as well

Comment: could you please elaborate? I don't quite understand what you mean. So, since the file is Test.zip and outputs to a file called temp.txt, I'd write it as temp.txt | findstr /i "feel"? What would the output of this string be?

Comment: that would output the line which it has feel word , if the search return no content then , there is no word matching in the output.

Comment: I just tried that and it just opens temp.txt and does nothing else. Can I get it to just register to a variable to say true, rather than just print out the line itself? Because I don't care to read what lines have it, I just want it to tell me if there is or isn't a file with that name in it.

Comment: input to findstr is the output from temp.txt, which was created by your zip content retrieval mechanism. Now if the content has the string you wished then the above command would print the line in command prompt , other wise it would print noting on the command line.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I don't want it to print the line, I just want it to change a variable to true or false depending on whether there is a file that matches inside. I don't want to actually see the contents cause that's excessive.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work. Doesn't this ALWAYS set result to true, even if it doesn't find it to be true?

Comment: no , because first line will set the value of result to  nothing , please find the command set result= , so i will be sure that result did not set true in each case , i have checked it is working fine.  please let me know if u face issue with a scenario.

Comment: I am facing an issue. I have set result=false each time and it then attempts to look for the word, prints nothing, and then still sets the variable to true. I know that that's the case because I have an if statement set to work should the variable be true, and it always executes, which is not right.